# MP3-encoding: Does CBR 320 cost more CPU than a lower bitrate?

Tags: mp3, lame

I have an Android-app which uses LAME to encode an audio live-stream to MP3.
Right now, I'm using a constant bitrate (CBR) of 128 for this.

Now I wonder, if I switch over to a bitrate of eg. 320, will this cost more CPU/take longer?

This is a mandatory part of the app as it's as mentioned a live-stream.. therefor I won't risk a higher CPU-usage or so.

Comment: There is no universal answer to this question as codecs can be implemented in different ways, each with their different characteristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MP3 encoders/decoders usually need more processing power for higher bit rates. I could find two data points, [MP3 encoder datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/sprs327/sprs327.pdf) and [MP3 decoder datasheet](http://www.kanecomputing.co.uk/pdfs/Ittiam-IA-MP3-Dec-ARM9E-DS.pdf.) to support this.

On a modern phone, the difference in the CPU loading should be insignificant, as MP3 decoding/encoding is less CPU intensive.

Comment: Thanks for the details Oak. That's at least correct for decoding. Would be great if we can find more details about ENcoding, though.

Comment: @MartinL. It holds good for encoding too. Have a look at this http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/sprs327/sprs327.pdf

Comment: @MartinL. I have updated the answer to incorporate encoding scenario.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your time and the provided sheets. Hope they can help other developers too!